# iOS - increase partial curl tap area to dismiss modal

Tags: objective-c, ios, partial-views, modalviewcontroller

Is there a way to do this? Like tapping on any part of the screen dismisses the partial modal curl.
I thought about an invisible button, but that still doesn't cover the whole curl area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add gesture recognizers to your main view in `viewDidLoad`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                action:@selector(getDismissed)];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                action:@selector(getDismissed)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

-(void)getDismissed
{
    // call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: by the presenting view controller
    // you can use delegation or direct call using presentingViewController property
}
```

Then exclude in view that you don't want to trigger the dismissal

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    // touching objects of type UIControl will not dismiss the view controller
    return ![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]];
}
```

Comment: thank you. I needed this a long time ago. but I'm looking forward for the next use. ;)